# Producer Consumer using intel-pin internal threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer, intel-pin

I am trying to implement a producer consumer model to separate the analysis and recording the data (collected from analysis) part of my pin tool. Going through the PIN thread API, I could not find any functions which can suspend a thread based on some predicate or signal a thread to resume (like `pthread_cond_wait()` and  `pthread_cond_signal()` in POSIX threads). So, is there any workaround to achieve the producer consumer model using existing functions while avoiding busy-waiting.

**NOTE:** Both producer and consumer threads are internal threads created by `PIN_SpawnInternalThread()`.

Comment: Not sure about how to handle internal PIN threads in a prod/cons way, but did you tried to use the [Fast buffered API](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__BUFFER__API.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the semaphore class provided in the Pin API. You can find examples of producer/consumer solutions that make use of semaphores in Windows.